# ¿Cómo cambiar una imagen en jlabel cada 5 minutos de forma automática?

Tags: java, java-swing

¿Cómo codificarían en java un `JLabel` que se actualize o cambie entre tres imágenes preseleccionadas cada 5 minutos?

Sería una analogía a un semáforo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En swing, puedes utilizar un [**`javax.swing.Timer`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) para ejecutar una tarea cada intervalo de tiempo.

Comment: +1 Puesto que la clase `Timer` es parte del JDK, no necesitas JARs externos.

Comment: Gracias luiggi exacto. Me estaba ahogando en un vaso de agua .

Answer (score 1):

puedes verificar el Quartz en java es bastante Util, desde ahi puedes lanzar tareas cada determinado tiempo https://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.1/ ya puedes hacer sin problemas el cambio del Jlabel en tu codigo

Comment: El uso de quartz es más para procesos en background a través de relojes (crons).

Comment: Exelente daniel !!! No conocia quartz me sirve de mucho en el proyecto en el que estoy trabajando. Gracias .